# How can changed dynamically database name in select from linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname

SET @dbname = 'SERP'

SELECT TOP (200) a.GrpCode, a.GrpDesc, a.GrpType, a.TarazId, a.SumDesc, a.SumFlag
    FROM LINKEDSERVER1.@dbname.dbo.A_AccGroup a
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 
> Incorrect syntax near '@dbname'.

I want to change database in linked server. I'm trying in SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Change it to literal string and execute by exec like `exec('SELECT TOP (200) a.GrpCode, a.GrpDesc, a.GrpType, a.TarazId, a.SumDesc, a.SumFlag
    FROM LINKEDSERVER1.' + @dbname + '.dbo.A_AccGroup a')`

Comment: Why you don't use dynamic query?

Comment: I recommend against just injecting the value of the database name without sanitsation @doctorgu ; we have no idea where the value of coming from.

Comment: @Larnu In this case value is from @dbname variable. Questioner tried to combine @dbname with select statement. So I informed how to combine. If you don't want to combine you have to use like `if @dbname = 'A' select * from LINKEDSERVER1.A.dbo.A_AccGroup else if @dbname = 'B' select * from LINKEDSERVER1.B.dbo.A_AccGroup`

Comment: I think you missed my point, @doctorgu . I'll add emphasis: I recommend *against just injecting* the value of the database name **without sanitsation** @doctorgu. (`QUOTENAME` exists for a reason.)

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 2008 R2 has been completely unsupported for over 2 years; you should really be looking at upgrade paths (in truth, you should have started about 3 years ago).

Comment: @Larnu I see now. You means @dbname can have injection code like `A.dbo.A_AccGroup; delete from User; --`. So result SQL can be `select * from LINKEDSERVER1.A.dbo.A_AccGroup; delete from User; --.dbo.A_AccGroup`. So you do not recommend combining SQL if some anti injection was not used. You have a good point.

Comment: `openquery` lets you run arbitrary SQL against a linked server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15